# What is the reason for this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Java throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error when I run this function:

```
public int[] copySecondSlice(int[] array) {
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length/2];
    for (int i = array.length/2; i < array.length; i++) {
        assert i == 1;
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

I tried multiple assets to check that i is superior to 0 and inferior to my array's length, but nothing does the trick. Could someone help me understand my mistake here?

Comment: Well, `i` will reach `array.length - 1`, but `newArray` only has `array.length / 2` elements, so `newArray[i]` will eventually fail.

Comment: Of course. Thank you

Comment: `newArray` index should start from zero instead of `i`. Something like `for (int j=0, i = array.lenght/2; i < array.length; i++, j++) { newArray[j] = array[i]; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because you are trying to reach the index which is out of bound of array new Array.

See

```
int[] newArray = new int[array.length/2];
```

Here you declare *length of newArray is* **array.length/2**

And

```
for (int i = array.length/2; **i < array.length**; i++) {
 newArray[**i**] = array[i];
```

Your condition will allow for to iterate till `array.length-1` so newArray is supposed to fill till that index i.e `array.length-1`. But our length of newArray is only `array.length/2` so it is going out of bound.

as @RP said you can correct it.

`newArray` index should start from 0 instead of `i`. Something like

```
  for (int j=0, i = array.lenght/2; i < array.length; i++, j++) { 
       ...
       newArray[j] = array[i];
```